# Hi.. i want to sign in from linkedin in my website

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, linkedin-api, incremental-linking

i've seen some tutorial for it. **they are showing about external linkedin api.**
where can i download this api.

i created app and login could successfull.  **how can i retrieve r_basicdatails from linkedin.** i've redirect callback function in codeigniter controller.  what code can i put in controller function to get data from linkedin.

when user clicked on linkedin signin. it is redirect to  .  linkedin function of register controler.  what code should i put in linkedin function.  help me out please .

Comment: try this one https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client

Answer (score 1):

Here you are ->
https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-linkedin
BTW you looking for provider ;) 
In options you can choose what data you need

```
$options = [
    'state' => 'OPTIONAL_CUSTOM_CONFIGURED_STATE',
    'scope' => ['r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress'] // array or string
];
```